# Expectation of an absolute form to the power of 4.

Tags: expectation, exponentiation, absolute-value

does the following form

$$E|\beta+\alpha Z_{t}^{2}-2\alpha\delta+\alpha\delta^{2}|^{4}$$ means $$E(|\beta+\alpha Z_{t}^{2}-2\alpha\delta+\alpha\delta^{2}|^{4})$$ or
$$(E|\beta+\alpha Z_{t}^{2}-2\alpha\delta+\alpha\delta^{2}|)^{4}$$?

Comment: It means the first :$ E(|\cdots|^4)$

Comment: Yes I thought the same. Thanks